# Django ValueError in form

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to submit a form by pulling post data from form fields and plugging it into my view.

I have the following model

```
class ExerciseEdl(models.Model):
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Units, models.CASCADE)
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercises, models.CASCADE)
    equipment = models.ForeignKey(Equipment, models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    location = models.ForeignKey(Locations, models.SET('Unassigned'), db_column='location')
```

And the following view

```
def add_edl_item(request, unit_pk, ex_pk, *args, **kwargs):
    ex_instance = Exercises.objects.get(pk=ex_pk)
    unit_instance = Units.objects.get(pk=unit_pk)

    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST)
        ExerciseEdl.objects.update_or_create(
            unit=unit_instance,
            exercise=ex_instance,
            equipment=request.POST.get('equipment'),
            quantity=request.POST.get('quantity'),
            location=request.POST.get('location')
        )
        messages.success(
            request, f'{unit_instance.unit_name} EDL for {ex_instance.exercise} successfully updated')
        return redirect('exercise-equipment', ex_pk=ex_pk, unit_pk=unit_pk)

    else:
        messages.error(
            request, f'Failed to update the {unit_instance.unit_name} EDL for {ex_instance.exercise}.')
```

And I am using data from this form to input the equipment, quantity, and location fields.

```html
<form action="{% url 'add-edl-item' ex_pk=ex_instance.id unit_pk=unit_instance.id %}" method="post">
                  {% csrf_token %}

                  <label for="equipment">Equipment</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="id_equipment" name="equipment">
                      {% for equip in equip_list %}
                    <option value="{{equip.id}}">{{equip.tamcn}} - {{equip.nomen}}</option>
                      {% endfor %}
                    </select>

                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="quantity" class="form-label">Quantity</label>
                    <input id= "id_quantity" type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity">
                  </div>

                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="location">Location</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="id_location" name="location" value="">
                      {% for loc in locations %}
                    <option value="{{loc.id}}">{{loc.location}}</option>
                      {% endfor %}
                    </select>

                  </div>
                  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
              </form>
```

The quantity is fine, it's just an integer, the other two fields however, give the following error

> ValueError: Cannot assign "'6'": "ExerciseEdl.equipment" must be a
> "Equipment" instance.

Where 6 is just the id for one of the options selected. If I selected another option before submitting the form, it would be the id of that option, the same thing applies to the location field. Using pk instead of id in the template returns the same error.

I thought the single quotes within the double quotes around the 6 might be the problem, so I set a static value for those two fields and it returned the same error, but with "6" instead of "'6'".

I also ran the debugger in vscode with breakpoints on every line in the view and submitted the form, but it skips over the update_or_create function without returning any information on it.

print(request.POST) prints this:

> <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken':
> ['03E5KcrhBapq7dkClg4JTcomzYQy32bskkDwWe5474cD3ITgS8kb88HtDIZzeRZw'],
> 'equipment': ['6'], 'quantity': ['12'], 'location': ['1']}>

using equip in the template instead of equip.id returns this error

> ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'A00267G'.

It says it wants an integer, but won't accept one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get Equipment instance and location instance. Make sure the id is integer and get the instance of both the model.

```
equipment_obj = Equipment.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('equipment'))
location_obj = Locations.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('location'))
ExerciseEdl.objects.update_or_create(
    unit=unit_instance,
    exercise=ex_instance,
    equipment=equipment_obj,
    quantity=request.POST.get('quantity'),
    location=location_obj
)
```